# How does a free particle travel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

Assume we have an electron at rest in an empty universe; i.e. no external fields or other particles to interact with. How does the electron's wave function and probability density propagate through space? Or do the wave function and probability density remain static? If possible, please explain without going too much into the mathematics as I have yet to learn the specifics of Schrodinger's equation, etc.

Comment: It's hard to say anything meaningful about motion in a universe with a single particle. Without anything to interact with, every position is the same as every other from the particle's point of view, so who's to say that space exists at all?

Comment: Fine, so then there exist other particles, but assume that they are far enough away that they can be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Gaussian wave packet,
\begin{align*}
  \psi(x,t) &=
  \frac{\sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}}{\sqrt{\alpha+\frac{i\hbar}{m}}}
  \exp
  \left[
    \frac{imv}{\hbar} \left( x-\frac{vt}{2} \right)-
    \frac{(x-vt)^2}{2\left( \alpha+\frac{i\hbar t}{m} \right)}
  \right] \\
  \phi(k,t) &=
  \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}} \exp
  \left[
    -\frac{i\hbar k^2 t}{2m}
    -\frac{\alpha}{2} \left( k-\frac{mv}{\hbar} \right)^2
  \right] \\
  \langle x \rangle &= vt \\
  \langle k \rangle &= \frac{mv}{\hbar} \\
  \Delta x &= \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2} \left( 1+\frac{\hbar t^2}{m^2} \right)} \\
  \Delta k &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Consider De Broglie's theory of matter having wave like properties. A free particle will propagate with wave like properties.

The wave function for a free particle is well defined in quantum mechanics. As you begin quantum mechanics, you'll encounter a finite square well, where if the energy of the particle is larger than the potential walls which make up the well, the particle is considered a "free particle", with wave equation:

$\Psi(r,t) = Ae^{i(kr-\omega t)} = Ae^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(pr-Et)}$

where $p$ is momentum.

The point being, the wave function propagates like a constant trig function through space. Give the wikipedia article a read (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_particle)